# React functional component behaviour question

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, memoization, react-functional-component

I'm starting to learn React and its components, specifically the functional components.
While playing around with the code i found out a particular behavior that left me with a doubt/question. I'm using React18, React-dom18 and Babel through CDN.
My IDE is "Webstorm".
I deliberately writed the code like this just to test out this behaviour, i know it's probably not optimal.

The code i used is all inside an HTML file and i have not used any additional setup or configuration:

```js
const RecipeTitle = ({test = 0}) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState(test);
  function onChangeHandler(){
    setTitle(1);
    console.log("onChange event! title: " + title);
  }
  console.log("Functional component executing. title: " + title);
  console.log("------------------------");
  return <input type="text" value={title} onChange={onChangeHandler} />
};

const container = document.querySelector("#root");
const rootElement = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
rootElement.render(<RecipeTitle />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I have a RecipeTitle component that gets rendered the first time when the application runs. This component have a state(title) and generate an "input" element in the DOM in which you can insert text; This element will always show the state value(title) in the web page because of the "value" prop setted on the element.
When the user try to change the text inside the input element(no matter what he press on his keyboard) the onChange event will trigger that will execute the "onChangeHandler" function, in this function i set the state value(title) always to "1"(this cause the text showed in the input element to be always "1" no matter what but this is not my concern). I added 3 "console.log()" to show better my doubt.
My doubt is happening when the user try to change the text inside the input element from the web page the second time.

The first time the "setTitle" method gets called he sets the state value from "0" to "1" so he re-runs the whole function to update the value showed in the input element in the web page (and that's okay).

The second time the "setTitle" method gets called he sets the state value from "1" to "1", so it didn't changed at all, even so the whole function get re-executed again (i know this by the logs, printed in the browser console, that are outside of "onChangeHandler" method) but the "input" element dosen't get re-rendered again (i know this by using "React Developer Tools", specifically the "profiler" tab that highlights the elements when they get re-rendered)(this is the unexpected behaviour, because i was expecting he behaves like the third time and all the times after the second one which i explain just below).

The third and all the times after the second one that the "setTitle" method gets called, he sets the state value from "1" to "1", so it didn't changed at all, the whole function **DOSEN'T** get re-executed again(he executes only the "onChangeHandler" method and that's it, and also the "input" element dosen't get re-rendered again (this is the behaviour i was expecting to happen from the second time already and not starting from the third time moving fowards).

So for summarizing, my question is: why he starts to ignore the execution of the whole functional component **STARTING FROM** the third time that the "onChange" event get triggered if it's, instead, from the second time already that state value starts to be setted to always the same value as before(it didn't change)? It is some kind of React internal optimization that he do? if yes: how it works explained in a brief way? any clarification about this can be helpful for me.

Here i leave a screenshot that show my doubt:

[doubt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVlR5.png)

Thank you very much for any help, i already tried to search for this behaviour online but without result.

P.S: I know about hooks.

EDIT: I got an answer from a friend that i post here so maybe can help other people as well to understand a little better this behaviour:

Generally speaking, when our code works correctly and doesn't cause an infinite chain of "re-renders", as in your case, the trigger should go off as you claim already in the first change from 1 to 1.
However, getting into the change detection mechanisms and establishing exactly when a component should or shouldn't be re-updated risks being a discreet "bloodbath". React is master of triggering the refresh, even in circumstances other than the change of state in the components...
This in general:
In particular I found this behavior is also documented as "Bailing out of a state update" in the hook reference. It is explained that React "might" still need to render our component before being able to "baling out". It shouldn't be a very expensive operation.. but if there are performance problems you could evaluate the possibility of using the useMemo hook.. and "cache" the most expensive points of the re-rendering.
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but what I suspect might be happening is, the way React memoizes changes might involve both the before- and after- states. The first time you enter a value, it changes it from '0' to '1', so it's memoized what happens as [0,1], and then the second time, even though the value hasn't changed, it's checking against the key [1,1], and since that before-after pair doesn't exist yet, it generates it all fresh. After that, [1,1] is memoized and so further 'changes' to 1 are just seen as being this previously rendered, memoized value.

Comment: can't say much but I found out that your default value of function is weird. I don't think that you can `( { test = 0 })` . If you want your default value of test to be 0, it must be `(props = {test : 0})`.

Comment: @Anji I tried to modify the code with your suggestion but now i'm getting an error in console when i try to modify the text inside the input element: [link](https://ibb.co/1TR8Mf4)

Comment: @TKoL thanks for the answer. Hmmm, maybe it can be; What i have also noticed is that if you change the argument value you are passing to the "setValue" function from "1" to "0" (so it will always be "0" and the state will NEVER change) it will start to ignore the component function execution from the very first time you trigger the "onChange" event. I leave you a screenshot so you can understand better: [link](https://ibb.co/D1vPGDQ)
What do you think about this?

Comment: @CristianScalingi sorry for confusing. ( not relate to ypur problem but I think it good to share ). It's  turn out that React component will always passing props parameter. if you not passing anything to the component ( as what u did ) it will pass empty object to function`{}`. which will overwrite the default value ( that I show u ). And I dunno that you can specify object default value like that.

Comment: React will often do shallow compares for DOM updates, why we get two passes here I'm not 100% sure, but -> `any clarification about this can be helpful for me.`   No it won't be helpful, please don't rely on this, future version may or may not do this, so I would suggest you don't worry too much on how React renders & any internal optimisations used.  If it's just curiosity, then that's fine, but certainly don't rely on that behaviour been there or not when you start to create your apps.

Comment: @Keith Thanks for the info, I wasn't aware that this specific behavior is susceptible to changes in future React updates. I'd still be curious to know why he has this behavior but at least now that I know that all this could change, sooner or later, I don't worry about it so much anymore.

Answer (score -1):

```
function onChangeHandler(){
  setTitle(1);
  console.log("onChange event! title: " + title);
}
```

Here the set title is set to 1 always. Whether it was 0 first or 1 first, it'll always be set to 1 right ?
Here's what i am assuming you want to do, you want to set the state of the title to what's being input by the user(since you are using an input component)

If thats the case, your onChangeHandler function should take an event object and set the title to the event.target.value in it.
Here's what the onChangeHandler should look like.

```
function onChangeHandler(event){
  setTitle(event.target.value);
  console.log("onChange event! title: " + title);
}
```

Here' the changed component

```
const RecipeTitle = ({test = 0}) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState(test);
  
  function onChangeHandler(event){
    setTitle(event.target.value);
    
    console.log("onChange event! title: " + title);
    
  }

  console.log("Functional component executing. title: " + title);
  console.log("------------------------");

    return <input type="text" value={title} onChange={onChangeHandler} />
};
```

As mentioned, this is based on some assumptions that you want to take title as input and set the value to that and it makes sense.
In case this helps, please accept it.
If not, let me know what did I miss ?

Comment: Sorry if my request in this question was not entirely clear, thank you anyway for your answer but that's not what I asked for in the question.
The posted question serves only to resolve my doubt about a behavior that the code I posted is having. It's not that the code doesn't work and I want someone to fix it, I just want to understand why this behavior happens.

Comment: My doubt concerns the fact that, the second time that the text of the input element is modified, the functional component is re-executed, instead all the other subsequent times it is not (although the state value always remains the same both the second time and all other times thereafter).

Comment: The fact that the functional component is re-executed, the second time the text of the input element is modified, can be deduced from the logs printed in the browser console (as shown in the screenshot I posted), instead all subsequent times it happens this shows only the log inside the "onChangeHandler" function, this suggests that the functional component has not been re-executed after the second one.

P.S: Sorry if the comment is splitted by 3 but it was too long.